# Dialogs in an onchange event triggered by Watin

Tags: c#, jquery, unit-testing, watin

I have a site with a dropdown. When the user changes the dropdown, a confirm dialog appears asking them if they wish to change it. If they click yes, it continues, otherwise it stays the same. Pretty standard stuff.

However, when I got to writing the Watin unit test, it was a pain.

My html is a simple select list with an id of _stateList

This is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#_stateList').change(function() {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to change your state?'))
            //do something 
    });
});
```

So in Watin, I have an extension method to fire the change event:

```
public static void SelectWithChangeEvent(this SelectList selectList, string text)
{
    selectList.Select(text);
    string js = string.Format("$('#{0}').change();", selectList.Id);
    InternetExplorer.Browser.Eval(js); //This is where it hangs
}
```

That extension method is called here:

```
ConfirmDialogHandler dialogHandler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
using (new UseDialogOnce(InternetExplorer.Browser.DialogWatcher, dialogHandler))
{
    PageMapping.StateDropdown.SelectWithChangeEvent(stateName); //It never gets past here
    dialogHandler.WaitUntilExists(5);
    if(dialogHandler.Exists())
        dialogHandler.OKButton.Click();
    else
        Assert.Fail("No Dialog Appeared");
}
```

I really hope this isn't too much code, but I simply cannot figure out how to handle a dialog that is trigger in change event rather than a click event. In Watin, buttons have ClickNoWait(). Is there anything similar for Select? Or Eval? Or maybe a setting that says don't wait at all?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping your javascript in a setTimeout(function(){}); will allow Eval to return asynchronously.

```
public static void SelectWithChangeEvent(this SelectList selectList, string text) 
{ 
    selectList.Select(text); 
    string js = string.Format("setTimeout(function() {{$('#{0}').change();}}, 5);", selectList.Id); 
    InternetExplorer.Browser.Eval(js); //This is where it hangs 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score -2):

one of the reasons might be the fact you forgot to end your if statement.

Your code says:

```
i$(function() {
$('#_stateList').change(function() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to change your state?')
        //do something
```

});

While it should be:

```
$(function() {
    $('#_stateList').change(function() {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to change your state?')){
            //do something 
        }
});
```

Comment: One line if statements do not require braces. Also, that's not what the issue is here.

Comment: Okay, my bad then. Just thinking out loud there ;)